# View or search for unanswered questions with a certain tag

Tags: support, faq, tags, search, unanswered-questions

How do I view unanswered questions with a certain tag?

How do I search for unanswered questions with a specific tag (or tags)?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: Great question!!! I want to add that even though the suggestions below give a solution, I think it would be a good idea to make it more straight-forward, such as allow one to click on the interesting tags there and get the unanswered questions for that tag.

Comment: See the new [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/282094).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to the [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) page, scroll down and look to the tagged links in the right sidebar.

Otherwise, you can add your tag to the end of the following URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/

Comment: But there are only the 25 most used tags listed.  How can I get others?

Comment: @Harleqin:  Edited my answer to show how.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Weird, where do you find the "tagged links in the right sidebar"? Do you mean the selected tags listed under "favorite"?

Comment: @Pacerier That got removed from the sidebar some time ago. Your favorite tags work the same way, but it was a different list.

Comment: For newest : https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/laravel?tab=newest

Answer (score 10):

You can now also use the [advanced search](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) box like so:

```
[tag] answers:0
```

Which translates to a URL of:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag%5D+answers%3A0
```

Take note of URL encoding, such as this search or items with the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, but no answers:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+answers%3A0
```

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/<tag>

Answer (score 6):

Go to the unanswered questions page and choose the c# tag from the list of tags on the right.

Comment: That feature doesn't seem to be working quite yet.  I hope they get it fixed soon.

Comment: ...and sometimes to all unanswered questions.

Comment: It's working for me. Remember the unaswered list contains questions with no upvoted answers - not just questions with no answers at all.

Comment: It's working only when in the right side selected the "newest" or "votes" tab, but not the "mytags" tab.

Answer (score 2):

1. At the top of the page click on "Unanswered" to go to the [unanswered page](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).
2. In the upper right hand corner of the page click on either "Newest" or "Votes".
3. Now, scroll down and click the tag you wish to view from the list under "Unanswered Tags" (you cannot use the tags listed under "Ignored Tags" or "Interesting Tags").

You should now see the unanswered questions with the tag you chose. **if you do not, read on.**

This is really confusing. There are several questions about it with the same answer and at first I thought they were all wrong.  However, it does work.  Here is the key:  You have to make sure that in the upper right hand corner either "Newest" or "Votes" is clicked.  If the "My Tags" tab is clicked it will not work correctly.

Comment: The last paragraph helped me. 
I don't know HOW they managed to make such a SIMPLE functionality so hard!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [/unanswered/tagged/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23) (which is c%23 because of url-limitations).

Answer (score 0):

Search for '[C#] or [CSS]', then click on Unanswered to find all questions for any topic you think you could answer.

For more info see: [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/stack-overflow-tag-filtering)