# How to sort unanswered questions by date?

Tags: discussion, support, search, unanswered-questions, timestamps

I saw the answer to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/view-or-search-for-unanswered-questions-with-a-certain-tag), but no where mentioned about **sorting by date** which I am asking in this question.

How to sort unanswered questions **by date**?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are referring to date asked, you can search `answers:0` (add [tagname] to the search if you wish to search by tag) and then select the "newest" tab. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Answers%3A0+%5Bsupport%5D&tab=newest) is a link to an example of that search method pre-done. If you want to search by date of lastest activity instead of date asked, do the steps above and use the "active" tab instead of the "newest" tab.

Comment: your `code` just working **fine**