# Make question list more browsable

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack overflow tag filtering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/stack-overflow-tag-filtering)

How about allowing users to browse the question list having selected some tags? A selection of this kind will make it easier to focus on questions in fields/languages they are experts in.

Comment: They are duplicate!

Comment: Do they answer your question?