# Is there a way to filter questions on combined tags + NOT tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

I just wanted to browse the feature requests on MSO here to see requests that are **not** tagged with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) yet, so I could see the ones that are still being discussed.

I found information regarding **and** and **or** tags: [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003/183189)

But I cannot seem to find information about a **not** operation.

Comment: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-declined+-status-completed`

Comment: @JoshCaswell should make that an answer :)

Comment: The answer is in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add those two to your Ignored Tags list and then search for [feature-request] and all questions tagged as such will be faded out in your search, but still present.

Comment: That may give a better overview on SO, but since these tags are red on meta, it would make little difference.

Comment: Yea, that is a really good point. I just figured it was worth mentioning at least that it was an option...

Comment: I know, and it was good thinking on your part.

Comment: Thanks, and Josh's comment/link to other answer works great!... from my 2second test.