# Search Questions by multiple tags with OR case

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, questions

Is there any way of searching the questions by multiple tags (OR Case)?

Like when I searched by `[php] [javascript]` it gives search results containing both `PHP` and `Javascript`. But I want to list all the questions that contains either `PHP` or `Javascript`.

Answer (score 3):

give this a try,

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+javascript?sort=newest&pagesize=50

or on the searchbox, add `OR` between tags:

```
[php] or [javascript] error
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+or+%5Bjavascript%5D+error

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do it like so:

```
[php] or [javascript]
```

See  also:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

[Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003/183189)