# Is it possible to save "or" tag filter?

Tags: support, tags, tag-filters

I read about [tag filtering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/stack-overflow-tag-filtering) and use the `[or]` keyword daily. This generates the following question from my behalf: is it possible to create and save a `[or]` filter, so that I don't have to write it every time in the search box? I tried the advanced tag subscription service but I was not able to get the desired effect (it does an implicit `[and]`). Maybe there's something I'm missing there and if so, I'd appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Bookmark the result page?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby, I thought about that, but I was looking for a more "persistent" solution. I browse on several devices (and platforms) and, although it's not such a big deal to bookmark a page, I find it convenient to just click a "pseudo search" tag.