# Filtered questions / tag sets with multiple tags using logical AND?

Tags: support, tags, filtering

Is there a way to create a tag set // filtered question group based on multiple tag criteria using logical AND?

Here's the [tag set page](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets).

There have been [other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags) that talk about how to do live searches, but I am talking about creating an actual tag set using the tag set page.

You can add multiple tags, but it will return any posting that fits any of those tags. The syntax of `[tag1] AND [tag2]` works when browsing StackExchange sites, but not on the actual filter questions page.

Is this not a feature? Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not a feature yet.

You can achieve that programmatically using the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).