# Create New "Filtered Questions" with Multiple Tags (Tag1 AND Tag2)

Tags: support, filtering, tag-filters

I would like to save a "Filtered Questions" with more than one tag. I know how to search for questions with multiple tags, but my question is about creating a "New Filter" to include questions from all sites with two tags.

The interface for creating a new filter (below) only allows one tag to be entered and does not (seem to) accept logical operators. Adding multiple rules allows for questions with each tag to be included, not questions with BOTH tags.

Many [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274528/filtered-questions-tag-sets-with-multiple-tags-using-logical-and) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags?rq=1) have been asked, but I have not found an answer yet.

(I tried for 30 minutes to upload an image, but this is not working.)

Comment: If the images would work I believe my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224536/158100) will do what you want.

Comment: I think your solution simply shows question with Tag1 OR Tag2. I want to see "Filtered Questions" with Tag1 AND Tag2.

Comment: Yeah, images are screwed at the moment, something at imgur's end.