# Filtering unanswered questions with multiple tags doesn't work

Tags: bug, tags, unanswered-questions, tag-filters

I know we can generally [filter questions with multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags).
However, if I want to filter unanswered questions with multiple tags in an `and` manner, then it doesn't work and acts as if it was an `or`.
See for example the result with [java] and [python] in stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+python?tab=noanswers

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug, but in the meantime, you cna use the `answers:` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bpython%5D+answers%3A0

Comment: True, but easily fixed by using an advanced search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bpython%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano&mixed=0

Comment: in my case it's more `hasaccepted:no` but thanks for the tip !
Still a bug imho, as it's non expected behaviour.